# How to make file browser (apache)

Tags: java, apache, directory, file-browser

i've been assigned a project named " browser for documents ". I'm telling you the name of the project cause the teacher gaves us very few hints and asked us to ask and find everything ourselves so i will try to explain what i'm looking for as good as i can. So the project is about a web file browser(directory) in which there are documents(word, excel, pdf, etc) and the purpose is that the user will be able to perform the following actions on these documents.  1) A way for a good document presentantion( for examaple the ability to see a mini picture of the documents insides if you put the cursor on the documents name). 2) The ability to search for a key word in the file names and the insides of the documents. 3) The user will have to log in with his username and password in order to be able to take actions on the documents inside the directory and 4) the ability to be able to download these files not only 1 by 1 but also all together. 
These are some of the features that we have to acomplish. The only thing that we know is that we have to use "apache" in order to do some of this staff. Our problem is that we have no idea where to begin searching so if anyone can give us any hint it would be really really helpfull. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

This link about file browsing in java and apache,
maybe this could be as starting point to understand file browsing using apache,

https://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/file-browsing.html

I know this should be posted as a comment, but I can't do this now, my points are not enough to make comments,